# How can I replace a filename with .ear in a file-list using sed?

Tags: shell-script, sed, scripting, search, replace

I have a file whose contents look like:

```
/appl/as/var/spool/ears/mps/ear1.ear
...
```

I want to replace the name of only `ear1.ear` with `ear2.ear` and I am using the below `sed` command, but with no luck:

```
sed -i.bak s/*.ear/ear2.ear/g earlist.mps
```

where `earlist.mps` is the file name

I have tried:

```
sed -i.bak s/.*.ear/ear2.ear/g earlist.mps
```

but this replaces the whole file with `ear2.ear`.

Comment: `sed -i.bak '\|ear1|s|1\.|2.|' earlist.mps`

Comment: @Costas actually i dont know the name of `ear1.ear` ...ie old ear

Comment: In any way you should exactly indicate what do you want to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's|/[^/]\+\.ear$|/ear2.ear|' file
```

- It seaches for line ending with `.ear` (`$` matches the end of the line). The filename can be everything except a `/`: `[^/]\+`. The `+` indicates that a character (which is not a `/`) can be repreated 1 or more times.
- Then is replaces that match with `/ear2.ear`.

Comment: i guess it wont work if i dont know the name of `ear1.ear` .. means the old ear

Comment: @amolsingh Try it now, i edited the answer

Comment: its working man ..sorry for late reply ...

Comment: but for some reason i am unable to use variable in this 
eg ... `sed -i.bak 's|/[^/]\+\.ear$|/${e}|' earlist.mps`

Comment: The reason is the single quote, use double quotes instead; `sed -i.bak "s|/[^/]\+\.ear$|/${e}|" ...`

Comment: thnks a lot man